# How to use React Native vector icons?

Tags: react-native

I have just installed [React Native vector icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) with this comand:

```
npm install react-native-vector-icons
```

But if I use it in the index.android.js

```
<Icon name="ios-add" size={30} color="#4F8EF7" />
```

I get a square with a X in the center instead of the icon.

Why ?

EDIT:

If I try to install it with "npm install react-native-vector-icons --save", then I get this error:

```
C:\Users\xrobot\Desktop\React Native\AwesomeProject>npm install react-native-vector-icons --save

    npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
    npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "react-native-vector-icons" "--save"
    npm ERR! node v6.9.5
    npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
    npm ERR! path C:\Users\xrobot\Desktop\React Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules\.staging\react-native-vector-icons-73f301e7
    npm ERR! code EPERM
    npm ERR! errno -4048
    npm ERR! syscall rename

    npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\xrobot\Desktop\React Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules\.staging\react-native-vector-icons-73f301e7' -> 'C:\Users\xrobot\Desktop\React Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native-vector-icons'
    npm ERR!     at destStatted (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:25:7)
    npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29
    npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\xrobot\Desktop\React Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules\.staging\react-native-vector-icons-73f301e7' -> 'C:\Users\xrobot\Desktop\React Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native-vector-icons'
    npm ERR!     at Error (native)
    npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\xrobot\Desktop\React Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules\.staging\react-native-vector-icons-73f301e7' -> 'C:\Users\emiliano\Desktop\React Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native-vector-icons'
    npm ERR!     at destStatted (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:25:7)
    npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29
    npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\emiliano\Desktop\React Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules\.staging\react-native-vector-icons-73f301e7' -> 'C:\Users\xrobot\Desktop\React Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native-vector-icons'
    npm ERR!     at Error (native) parent: 'AwesomeProject' }
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\xrobot\Desktop\React Native\AwesomeProject\npm-debug.log

    C:\Users\xrobot\Desktop\React Native\AwesomeProject>npm install react-native-vector-icons
    AwesomeProject@0.0.1 C:\Users\xrobot\Desktop\React Native\AwesomeProject
    `-- react-native-vector-icons@4.0.0
```

EDIT 2:

```
C:\Users\xrobot\Desktop\React Native\AwesomeProject>react-native link react-native-vector-icons
rnpm-install info Linking react-native-vector-icons android dependency
rnpm-install info Android module react-native-vector-icons has been successfully linked
rnpm-install info Linking react-native-vector-icons ios dependency
rnpm-install info iOS module react-native-vector-icons has been successfully linked
rnpm-install info Linking assets to ios project
rnpm-install WARN ERRGROUP Group 'Resources' does not exist in your XCode project. We have created it automatically for you.
rnpm-install info Linking assets to android project
rnpm-install info Assets have been successfully linked to your project
```

EDIT 3:

I have removed the app from the physical device and then I re-build it ( as QMFNP  said ). Now it works

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First, make sure you're saving the dependency in your project by doing:

`npm install react-native-vector-icons --save`. Including the `--save` is necessary, otherwise `react-native link` won't be able to locate the module.

[image: see attached screenshot]

Before you can use them in your iOS or Android project, you also have to link the native modules. The quick way to do this is by using the following command:

`react-native link react-native-vector-icons`

If for any reason you have problems using `react-native link` to link the native modules, the `react-native-vector-icons` [README](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/blob/master/README.md) also provides detailed instructions for linking them manually on Android and iOS, and integrating the library on the web as well.

Comment: react-native link return me " Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\xrobot\Desktop\React Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native-vector-icons\package.json'"

Comment: @xRobot this is the result of not saving the react-native-vector-icons dependency. I'm able to reproduce your error if I run `npm install react-native-vector-icons` and `react-native link react-native-vector-icons`. In order to fix it, you have to be sure to include the `--save` at the end of your `npm install` so it creates the `react-native-vector-icons` folder inside of your `node_modules` folder. The full command is `npm install react-native-vector-icons --save`.

Comment: @xRobot I've updated my answer to include what happens when you don't include `--save` in your `npm install` command.

Comment: If I include --save, I get an error. See the edited question above to see it please :)

Comment: @xRobot can you try running `npm cache clean` as mentioned here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10826 ?

Comment: ok npm cache clean fixed the problem and now it's installed with --save. Then I have linked it with "react-native link..." but I still see a square with an X in the center ( I have re-edited the question above ). Thanks :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136483/discussion-between-qmfnp-and-xrobot).

Comment: This worked for me perfectly, I kept ignoring the --save part and it ended up costing me badly. I just did the npm install and then linked it and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 18):

Here is full **UPDATED** answer, **just follow these steps** :-

**1.** `npm install react-native-vector-icons --save`
**2.** `react-native link`
**3.** `react-native link react-native-vector-icons`
**4.** import `Icon` using one of these ( as per your requirement )

```
   **MaterialCommunityIcons**

    import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
   **Ionicons**

    import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

   **FontAwesome5**

    import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
```

**5.** Uses (JSX)

```
     <Icon size={24} color="white" name="movie" />
```

Answer (score 16):

Step 1: 
Install react-native-element:

```
npm install react-native-elements --save
```

Steps 2: Install react-native-vector-icons
Install from npm

```
npm install react-native-vector-icons --save
```

Link it

```
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

After that you can use it in your page by: 
Step 1:

```
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
```

Step 2:

```
<Icon name="md-beer" type="ionicon" color="#887700" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you are not importing correctly the library, you must specify a family of **icons** you wanna use.

I think the name of the icon you are using not correspond with the icon you are searching.

For example, if you will use material icons, the import will be: 
`import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';`

And change the name to `name={add}`

Try look for other icons family if you don want use material icons.

Comment: Based on the error they're getting when they try running `react-native link` it appears that `react-native-vector-icons` doesn't exist inside of the `node_modules` folder yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
icon = {"<"Icon name='lock'/>}
```

Or :

```
icon = {{ type:'font-awesome',name:'lock'}}
```

in any React native componant property.

Comment: Giving Icon component property as icon = {{ type:'font-awesome',name:'lock'}} doesnt seems to work

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help, at least this is what I have to do every time. In the `Project/android/app/build.gradle`, add this line:

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

Answer (score 0):

follow this step manual
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#option-manually-1

this may help some one install react native vector icon with cmd and follow every manual step but leave the mainApplication.java which is at android>app>src>main>java>com>youApplication>mainApplication.java
comment it out if you run the auto linkng command which is
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
//import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
// Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
// packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
// packages.add(new VectorIconsPackage());
and rebuild your app this work for me I'm able to find it out in total more than 10hours

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue as the root cause might be those font files are not copied into the right place for RN to use.

I followed the steps listed here: https://aboutreact.com/react-native-vector-icons/ which works for me, while `npm link` solution does not work for me.

My env is as follows,

- npm: `10.2.0`
- node: `v21.1.0`
- os: `macOS Ventura`
- xcode: `15.0.1`

My steps are as follows,

1. `npm install react-native-vector-icons --save`
2. `npx pod-install` or `cd iOS && pd install`
3. Importing Icon Files in iOS

   1. Create a `fonts` directory in ios and copy all the font files from `node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts` into it
   2. Now open the project `YourProject` -> `ios` -> `YourProject.xcworkspace` in Xcode.
   3. After opening the project in Xcode click on the project from the left sidebar to open the options and select Add Files to “YourProjectName”
   4. Select the `fonts` directory which you have created. Remember to select `Create Folder references` from below and click `Add`
   5. Edit `info.plist` and add fonts configuration

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>fonts/FontAwesome.ttf</string>
    <string>fonts/Ionicons.ttf</string>
    <string>fonts/Foundation.ttf</string>
    <string>fonts/MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>fonts/MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
</array>
```

Then rerun the build CLI and you should be enable to see the icons.