# How to use Icons in react-native-vector?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm facing a blocker with react-native-vector-icons library, whenever I try to render an Icon, it is always showing a "?" sign. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, everything seems to be okay.
Here are the steps to reproduce what I'm facing

1. import package

```js
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
```

2. Try to render this icon

```js
<Icon name="send" size={16} color="white" />
```

The outcome is an "?" mark. I was thinking that it might be the naming of the icon but I cross-check everything is good. I need  help :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42420931/how-to-use-react-native-vector-icons

Comment: @Variable hello, link package?

Comment: ```react-native link react-native-vector-icons```

Comment: Hola @SandipNirmal, it is showing `Looks like you installed react-native globally, maybe you meant react-native-cli?
To fix the issue, run:`

Comment: Install ``react-native`` locally

Comment: Is it in your package.json?

Comment: Hey @TallPaul, yep i can see that `react-native-vector` is under dependencies and have version "^6.0,2"

Comment: @MichealMuller are you using expo?

Comment: @Micheal you need to specify the platform you need ex `md-send` or `ios-send`

Comment: @MichealMuller did what Naveed say fix your issue?